# Splunk: Find events that don't have a certain attribute logged as different log lines

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula, splunk-calculation

We have Splunk logs like:

```
ts=20:10:01 id=1 state=first foo=bar
ts=20:10:05 id=1 state=second foo=bar
ts=20:10:06 id=1 state=third foo=bar

ts=20:10:03 id=2 state=first foo=bar

ts=20:11:01 id=3 state=first foo=bar
ts=20:11:03 id=3 state=second foo=bar
ts=20:11:05 id=3 state=third foo=bar
```

I would like to find all `id` that does not have the other 2 states. In this example all `id=2` that logged first state but not the other 2. I was reading on JOIN and found that it can only look at events that occur with both events but we can't exclude those events.

```
index=my-idx foo=bar 
| join id type=outer
  [search index=my-idx foo=bar NOT (state=second OR state=third) | table id]
| table id
```

The Query I am thinking of should return a list of ids that don't have the `state=second` or `state=third` which in the above example should return `id=2`

Comment: It is not clear exactly what you trying to achieve. Just to list the `id` where `foo=bar` and `state` value is not `second` or `third`? Are you looking for a distinct list of the `id` values?

Comment: @MadsHansen I am looking to get a list of all id like `id=2` which doesn't have the state=second or third logged.

Comment: Oh, okay - now I see. You would want to exclude id 1 and 3 because even though they have the event with state=first, they also have the other events with state=second and third.

Comment: @MadsHansen yes and thanks for asking that. Updated my question as well as it wasn't clear there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a run-anywhere example query that should do it.  Comments in the query explain what it does.  It assumes the first state of any id is always "first".

````
| makeresults 
| eval data="ts=20:10:01 id=1 state=first foo=bar;
ts=20:10:05 id=1 state=second foo=bar;
ts=20:10:06 id=1 state=third foo=bar;
ts=20:10:03 id=2 state=first foo=bar;
ts=20:11:01 id=3 state=first foo=bar;
ts=20:11:03 id=3 state=second foo=bar;
ts=20:11:05 id=3 state=third foo=bar"
| eval data=split(data,";")
| mvexpand data
| eval _raw=data
| extract kvdelim=" ", pairdelim="="
| fields ts,id,state,foo
```Above just sets up test data```
```Count how many different states each id has```
| streamstats dc(state) as count by id
```Find the highest count for each id```
| eventstats max(count) as max by id
```Select only those with a single state```
| where max=1
| table ts id state foo
````

Answer (score 1):

```
stats values(state) as all_states dc(state) as state_count by id
| search all_states="first" AND state_count=1
| table id
```